# Update a plot using iteration from loop

Tags: loops, matplotlib, animation, real-time-updates, livegraph

I want to plot 3 parameters in a line graph (revolutions Vs Thrust & Torque). Thrust and Torque are output of loop, which are required to plot live (update each time of iteration) with increasing revolution which depends upon the input time!

This is the result of code

```
Revolution     Thrust                   Torque                   
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1              3955.56        6307.18
2              3955.56        6307.18
3              3955.56        6307.18
4              3955.56        6307.18
5              3955.56        6307.18
6              3955.56        6307.18
7              3955.56        6307.18
8              3955.56        6307.18
9              3955.56        6307.18
10             3955.56        6307.18
11             3955.56        6307.18
12             3955.56        6307.18
13             3955.56        6307.18
14             3955.56        6307.18
15             3955.56        6307.18
16             3955.56        6307.18
17             3955.56        6307.18
18             3955.56        6307.18
19             3955.56        6307.18
20             3955.56        6307.18
21             3955.56        6307.18
22             3955.56        6307.18
23             3955.56        6307.18
24             3955.56        6307.18
```

All three parameters are generated with the following code!
Code is given!

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Basic data
azimuth = [14, 213, 345]
tilt = [0, 2, 4.5]
lat = [2, 3.75, 4.16]
long = [1.1, -1.1, 0.2]

# Generate the accumulative
accum_lat = [round(sum(lat[:i+1]), 2) for i in range(len(lat))]

# Average
avg_lat = [(lat[i] + lat[i+1]) / 2 if i != len(lat)-1 else lat[i] for i in range(len(lat))]

# Generate the accumulative
accum_long = [round(sum(long[:i+1]), 2) for i in range(len(long))]

# Define Radii
outer_radius = 65
inner_radius = 63

# Compute x , y and z
x = [round(((accum_lat[i] * math.cos(math.radians(azimuth[i])) - (inner_radius / 2)) - outer_radius), 2) for i in range(len(accum_lat))]

y = [round((accum_lat[i] * math.sin(math.radians(azimuth[i]))), 2) for i in range(len(accum_lat))]

max_accum_long = max(accum_long)
z_1 = [max_accum_long - x for x in accum_long]
z = [round(x, 2) for x in z_1]

# Define the Advance
advance_rate = 1.5

# Compute the actual advance
act_pen = [round((advance_rate * math.cos(math.radians(x))), 2) for x in tilt]

# Conditioning Inputs
RPM = 16
Time = 1.5
revolution = RPM * Time
radius_multiplier = 2 * math.pi

# Show headers of print function
headers = ['Revolution', 'Thrust', 'Torque']
separator = '-' * 65
print("{:<15}{:<25}{:<25}".format(*headers))
print(separator)

# Coefficients
N_N_a = 939
N_N_b = 0.1570
N_N_c = 0.289
N_M_a = 1858
N_M_b = 0.1590
N_M_c = 0.164
N_W_a = 2671
N_W_b = 0.1590
N_W_c = 0.181

# Coefficients
D_N_a = 471
D_N_b = 1.1070
D_N_c = 0.449
D_M_a = 471
D_M_b = 1.1070
D_M_c = 0.449
D_W_a = 492
D_W_b = 1.1740
D_W_c = 0.27

for rev in range(int(revolution)):
    for r in accum_lat:
        distance = [(rev+1)* (radius_multiplier * r) for _ in range(len(accum_lat))]
        distance_travel_list = [round(d, 2) for d in distance]

        # Conditions
        def get_condition(distance_travel_list):
            tool_cond = []
            for i, x in enumerate(distance_travel_list):
                if x < 5000:
                    tool_cond.append(1)
                elif 5000 <= x < 6000:
                    tool_cond.append(2)
                else:
                    tool_cond.append(3)
            return tool_cond
        tool_cond = get_condition(distance_travel_list)
        
# Normal
    NF = []
    for i in range(len(act_pen)):
        if tool_cond[i] == 1:
            NF.append(abs(N_N_a * (Avg_Lat[i]**N_N_b) * (act_pen[i]**N_N_c)))
        elif tool_cond[i] == 2:
            NF.append(abs(N_M_a * (Avg_Lat[i]**N_M_b) * (act_pen[i]**N_M_c)))
        elif tool_cond[i] == 3:
            NF.append(abs(N_W_a * (Avg_Lat[i]**N_W_b) * (act_pen[i]**N_W_c)))
    NF = [round(n, 2) for n in NF]

# Cut
    DF = []

    for i in range(len(act_pen)):
        if tool_cond[i] == 1:
            DF.append(abs(D_N_a * (Avg_Lat[i]**D_N_b) * (act_pen[i]**D_N_c)))
        elif tool_cond[i] == 2:
            DF.append(abs(D_M_a * (Avg_Lat[i]**D_M_b) * (act_pen[i]**D_M_c)))
        elif tool_cond[i] == 3:
            DF.append(abs(D_W_a * (Avg_Lat[i]**D_W_b) * (act_pen[i]**D_W_c)))
    DF = [round(n, 2) for n in DF]

    # Side
    s_percent = 0.15

    SF = [round(NF[i] * s_percent * (1 + math.sin(math.radians(Tilt[i]))), 2) for i in range(len(NF))]

    # NFX
    NFX = [round(NF[i] * math.sin(math.radians(Tilt[i])) * math.cos(math.radians(Azimuth[i])), 2) for i in range(len(NF))]

    # DFX
    DFX = [round(DF[i] * math.sin(math.radians(Azimuth[i])), 2) for i in range(len(DF))]

    # SFX
    SFX = [round(SF[i] * math.cos(math.radians(Tilt[i])) * math.cos(math.radians(Azimuth[i])), 2) for i in range(len(SF))]

    # Create a new list for the results
    FX = [round(-NFX[i] - DFX[i] + SFX[i], 2) for i in range(len(NFX))]
    Lat_Force = sum(FX)

    # NFY
    NFY = [round(NF[i] * math.sin(math.radians(Tilt[i])) * math.sin(math.radians(Azimuth[i])), 2) for i in range(len(NF))]

    # DFY
    DFY = [round(DF[i] * math.cos(math.radians(Azimuth[i])), 2) for i in range(len(DF))]

    # SFY
    SFY = [round(SF[i] * math.cos(math.radians(Tilt[i])) * math.sin(math.radians(Azimuth[i])), 2) for i in range(len(SF))]


    # Create a new list
    FY = [round(-NFY[i] + DFY[i] + SFY[i], 2) for i in range(len(NFY))]
    Vertical_Force = sum(FY)

    # NFZ
    NFZ = [round(NF[i] * math.cos(math.radians(Tilt[i])), 2) for i in range(len(NF))]

    # SFZ
    SFZ = [round(SF[i] * math.sin(math.radians(Tilt[i])), 2) for i in range(len(SF))]

    # Create a new list
    FZ = [round(NFZ[i] + SFZ[i], 2) for i in range(len(NFZ))]
    Thrust = sum(FZ)

    # Iterate over the data
    XFY = [round((x[i]+106.5) * FY[i], 2) for i in range(len(FY))]

    XFZ = [round(x[i] * FZ[i], 2) for i in range(len(FZ))]

    YFZ = [round(y[i] * FZ[i], 2) for i in range(len(FZ))]

    YFX = [round(y[i] * FX[i], 2) for i in range(len(FX))]

    ZFY = [round(z[i] * FY[i], 2) for i in range(len(FY))]

    ZFX = [round(z[i] * FX[i], 2) for i in range(len(FX))]

    # Create a new list
    MX = [round((-YFZ[i] + ZFY[i]) / 12, 2) for i in range(len(YFZ))]

    MY = [round((XFZ[i] - ZFX[i]) / 12, 2) for i in range(len(ZFX))]
    Lat_Moment = sum(MY)

    MZ = [round((XFY[i] - YFX[i]) / 12, 2) for i in range(len(YFX))]
    Torque = [round(sum(MZ), 2)]

    # Convert Thrust and Torque to list if they are not already
    if not isinstance(Thrust, list):
        Thrust = [Thrust]
    if not isinstance(Torque, list):
        Torque = [Torque]

# Calculate the results
    Thrust = sum(FZ)
    Torque = sum(MZ)
    Revolutions = [rev]
    print("{:<15.0f}{:<15.2f}{:.2f}".format(rev+1, Thrust, Torque))
```